# Progress during large file copy (Copy-Item & Write-Progress?)

Tags: powershell, progress-bar, progress, copying, copy-item

Is there any way to copy a really large file (from one server to another) in PowerShell AND display its progress?

There are solutions out there to use Write-Progress in conjunction with looping to copy many files and display progress.  However I can't seem to find anything that would show progress of a single file.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I haven't heard about progress with `Copy-Item`. If you don't want to use any external tool, you can experiment with streams. The size of buffer varies, you may try different values (from 2kb to 64kb).

```
function Copy-File {
    param( [string]$from, [string]$to)
    $ffile = [io.file]::OpenRead($from)
    $tofile = [io.file]::OpenWrite($to)
    Write-Progress -Activity "Copying file" -status "$from -> $to" -PercentComplete 0
    try {
        [byte[]]$buff = new-object byte[] 4096
        [long]$total = [int]$count = 0
        do {
            $count = $ffile.Read($buff, 0, $buff.Length)
            $tofile.Write($buff, 0, $count)
            $total += $count
            if ($total % 1mb -eq 0) {
                Write-Progress -Activity "Copying file" -status "$from -> $to" `
                   -PercentComplete ([long]($total * 100 / $ffile.Length))
            }
        } while ($count -gt 0)
    }
    finally {
        $ffile.Dispose()
        $tofile.Dispose()
        Write-Progress -Activity "Copying file" -Status "Ready" -Completed
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution.

When I tried it I received an error - 
Cannot convert value "2147483648" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."

After replacing the [int] to a [long], it worked great.

Thanks

Comment: That means that you copy files bigger than 2GB? I guess so. I'm glad it works :)

Comment: +1 simple solutions are best! Am copying big (8GB+) files across from one network location to another ... gigabit network ... (*indication only*) ... using blocks of 1Mb means network adapter runs at about 50% (I suspect some throttling on our switch) ... smaller blocks weren't great though.

Comment: Small .NETy gripe: the finally should call Dispose() rather than Close(). Good solution though. I'm sad there's no built-in progress available.

Comment: Right, missing using statement in PowerShell :)

Comment: @TheXenocide Why?  Stream.Close() just calls Stream.Dispose()?  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs

Comment: That's right, but basically whenever the object is IDisposable, I call Dispose(). Imo it's safer and also you don't need to know the internals.

Comment: Well, this is more of a programming quip than a scripting one (if you choose to differentiate), but from a computer science point of view: you are relying on internal implementation details of an object which are not guaranteed and can change at any time, and additionally not following an established pattern for the public contract. This both violates a primary tenant of object oriented design and also ignores the public IDisposable contract (which you *are* supposed to know exists) that has well established best practices that state it should always be disposed.

Comment: You should replace the `[io.file]::OpenWrite($to)` to `[io.file]::Create($to)` otherwise it will not overwrite files properly.

Comment: What does it mean "properly"?

Comment: If anyone is trying to get this to work with a PSDrive you'll want to change $ffile initialization to (Get-ChildItem $from).OpenRead()   and the $tofile initialization to (new-item $to -Type File -Force).OpenWrite()

Comment: I changed the [int]$total into [long]$total to take large files into account, like Jason suggested.

Comment: Need to handle exception on 0 length files.  Currently gets a divide by zero error when it come across files like that.

Answer (score 135):

It seems like a much better solution to just use BitsTransfer, it seems to come OOTB on most Windows machines with PowerShell 2.0 or greater.

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $Source -Destination $Destination -Description "Backup" -DisplayName "Backup"
```

Comment: Great! Indeed, this also gives me a (powershell) progress indicator.

Comment: it wouldn't probably leverages BITS capabilities if you are not pulling source from remote location, but it works smooth.

Comment: Exactly what I was after- worked perfectly and gives a progress bar!

Comment: I used this to copy VMs around in 2012 R2 Hyper-V free.

Comment: I'm using this on a Hyper-V Server with minimal GUI and it works great!

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: Does not work with Powershell Core 6.1.0 at least. I get an import error saying "BitsTransfer.psd1 does not support current PowerShell edition 'Core'"

Comment: Strangely, when I run the command, nothing at all happens with no output? I use for example -Source "\\comp1\c$\folder" -Destionation "\\comp2\c$\folder" , any idea what could be wrong? I have access to both folders, no issue there. If I use copy-item it works but with no progress obviously.

Comment: In Ps 5.1 I get: `user is not registered in Network.` I copy from Network share. I use the 2 Parameters `source` and `Destination`.

Comment: @Rakha Think `Start-BitsTransfer` only works on files not directories. Unfortunately you can't even specify wildcards for files.

Comment: Seemed worth noting:  I'm working with 20-100mb files over a slow VPN, found Start-BitsTransfer to be consistently ~25% slower than the FileStream.Write method used in the Copy-Files answer (with 1mb buffer size).

Answer (score 34):

```
cmd /c copy /z src dest
```

not pure PowerShell, but executable in PowerShell and it displays progress in percents

Comment: Great answer. I also used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31015007/4163002) to output progress.

Answer (score 33):

Alternativly this option uses the native windows progress bar...

```
$FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG = "&H0&"

$objShell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"

$objFolder = $objShell.NameSpace($DestLocation) 

$objFolder.CopyHere($srcFile, $FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG)
```

Comment: This is brilliant, how do you specify the "ALWAYS OVERWRITE" flag for this method, is it possible? So it doesn't prompt when files exist.

Comment: @Rakha you just need to pass 16 as sec param to CopyHere function like this: `$objFolder.CopyHere($srcFile, 16)`

Answer (score 17):

I amended the code from stej (which was great, just what i needed!) to use larger buffer, [long] for larger files and used System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class to track elapsed time and estimate time remaining.

Also added reporting of transfer rate during transfer and outputting overall elapsed time and overall transfer rate.

Using 4MB (4096*1024 bytes) buffer to get better than Win7 native throughput copying from NAS to USB stick on laptop over wifi.

On To-Do list:

- add error handling (catch)
- handle get-childitem file list as input
- nested progress bars when copying multiple files (file x of y, % if
  total data copied etc)
- input parameter for buffer size

Feel free to use/improve :-)

```
function Copy-File {
param( [string]$from, [string]$to)
$ffile = [io.file]::OpenRead($from)
$tofile = [io.file]::OpenWrite($to)
Write-Progress `
    -Activity "Copying file" `
    -status ($from.Split("\")|select -last 1) `
    -PercentComplete 0
try {
    $sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();
    [byte[]]$buff = new-object byte[] (4096*1024)
    [long]$total = [long]$count = 0
    do {
        $count = $ffile.Read($buff, 0, $buff.Length)
        $tofile.Write($buff, 0, $count)
        $total += $count
        [int]$pctcomp = ([int]($total/$ffile.Length* 100));
        [int]$secselapsed = [int]($sw.elapsedmilliseconds.ToString())/1000;
        if ( $secselapsed -ne 0 ) {
            [single]$xferrate = (($total/$secselapsed)/1mb);
        } else {
            [single]$xferrate = 0.0
        }
        if ($total % 1mb -eq 0) {
            if($pctcomp -gt 0)`
                {[int]$secsleft = ((($secselapsed/$pctcomp)* 100)-$secselapsed);
                } else {
                [int]$secsleft = 0};
            Write-Progress `
                -Activity ($pctcomp.ToString() + "% Copying file @ " + "{0:n2}" -f $xferrate + " MB/s")`
                -status ($from.Split("\")|select -last 1) `
                -PercentComplete $pctcomp `
                -SecondsRemaining $secsleft;
        }
    } while ($count -gt 0)
$sw.Stop();
$sw.Reset();
}
finally {
    write-host (($from.Split("\")|select -last 1) + `
     " copied in " + $secselapsed + " seconds at " + `
     "{0:n2}" -f [int](($ffile.length/$secselapsed)/1mb) + " MB/s.");
     $ffile.Close();
     $tofile.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice script, but it gives a divide by zero. I had to add:  if ( $secselapsed -ne 0 ) {
          [single]$xferrate = (($total/$secselapsed)/1mb);
        } else {
          [single]$xferrate = 0.0
        }

Comment: Not something I've come across in my daily use of this code, what powershell version are you using? Does it ever work for you? Just curious. Anything that makes it more robust is fine by me :-)

Comment: On Powershell 2.0.1.1 it did work intermittently, but most times not. It seemed it might be copying the first block too fast and then rounding down the $secelapsed. I've put in the update, might save someone some time. Thanks again, it's a useful script.

Comment: I owe @stej for the original code that I adapted, but thanks :-)

Comment: Nice script, but the divide by zero error is in the line: "{0:n2}" -f [int](($ffile.length/$secselapsed)/1mb) + " MB/s.");     You check for $secselapsed -eq 0 up above in the script, but don't at that point.

Comment: You should replace the `[io.file]::OpenWrite($to)` to `[io.file]::Create($to)` otherwise it will not overwrite files properly.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain never had a single overwrite fail with the `::OpenWrite` method yet but will bear that in mind if I do

Comment: @GrahamGold Copy a file, then copy a 2nd file with the same name but a smaller filesize. The resultant file will have the end of the first file tacked on after the end of the 2nd file.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain explains why I wouldn't hit it in my usage of the above code - that scenario isn't possible in the script where I use it, if overwrite option is chosen at runtime then each file existing file is renamed as a temp file name before new file copied then temp file removed on completion of copy.

Comment: How do I get Start-BitsTransfer (really, Write-Progress) to log updates as text to standard output instead of just the PowerShell progress bar?

Answer (score 9):

Not that I'm aware of.  I wouldn't recommend using copy-item for this anyway.  I don't think it has been designed to be robust like robocopy.exe to support retry which you would want for extremely large file copies over the network.

Comment: Valid point. In this particular case I'm not too worried about robustness. It's copying a 15gig file between two servers on the same back-plane. However in other situations I would definitely consider a more robust solution.

Answer (score 4):

Hate to be the one to bump an old subject, but I found this post extremely useful. After running performance tests on the snippets by **stej** and it's refinement by **Graham Gold**, plus the BITS suggestion by **Nacht**, I have decided that:

1. I *really* liked Graham's command with time estimations and speed readings.
2. I also *really* liked the significant speed increase of using BITS as my transfer method.

Faced with the decision between the two... I found that Start-BitsTransfer supported Asynchronous mode. So here is the result of my merging the two.

```
function Copy-File {
    # ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55527732/3626361
    param([string]$From, [string]$To)

    try {
        $job = Start-BitsTransfer -Source $From -Destination $To `
            -Description "Moving: $From => $To" `
            -DisplayName "Backup" -Asynchronous

        # Start stopwatch
        $sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
        Write-Progress -Activity "Connecting..."

        while ($job.JobState.ToString() -ne "Transferred") {
            switch ($job.JobState.ToString()) {
                "Connecting" {
                    break
                }
                "Transferring" {
                    $pctcomp = ($job.BytesTransferred / $job.BytesTotal) * 100
                    $elapsed = ($sw.elapsedmilliseconds.ToString()) / 1000

                    if ($elapsed -eq 0) {
                        $xferrate = 0.0
                    }
                    else {
                        $xferrate = (($job.BytesTransferred / $elapsed) / 1mb);
                    }

                    if ($job.BytesTransferred % 1mb -eq 0) {
                        if ($pctcomp -gt 0) {
                            $secsleft = ((($elapsed / $pctcomp) * 100) - $elapsed)
                        }
                        else {
                            $secsleft = 0
                        }

                        Write-Progress -Activity ("Copying file '" + ($From.Split("\") | Select-Object -last 1) + "' @ " + "{0:n2}" -f $xferrate + "MB/s") `
                            -PercentComplete $pctcomp `
                            -SecondsRemaining $secsleft
                    }
                    break
                }
                "Transferred" {
                    break
                }
                Default {
                    throw $job.JobState.ToString() + " unexpected BITS state."
                }
            }
        }

        $sw.Stop()
        $sw.Reset()
    }
    finally {
        Complete-BitsTransfer -BitsJob $job
        Write-Progress -Activity "Completed" -Completed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

i found none of the examples above met my needs, i wanted to copy a directory with sub directories, the problem is my source directory had too many files so i quickly hit the BITS file limit (i had > 1500 file) also the total directory size was quite large.

i found a function using robocopy that was a good starting point at https://keithga.wordpress.com/2014/06/23/copy-itemwithprogress/, however i found it wasn't quite robust enough, it didn't handle trailing slashes, spaces gracefully and did not stop the copy when the script was halted.

Here is my refined version:

```
function Copy-ItemWithProgress
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    RoboCopy with PowerShell progress.

    .DESCRIPTION
    Performs file copy with RoboCopy. Output from RoboCopy is captured,
    parsed, and returned as Powershell native status and progress.

    .PARAMETER Source
    Directory to copy files from, this should not contain trailing slashes

    .PARAMETER Destination
    DIrectory to copy files to, this should not contain trailing slahes

    .PARAMETER FilesToCopy
    A wildcard expresion of which files to copy, defaults to *.*

    .PARAMETER RobocopyArgs
    List of arguments passed directly to Robocopy.
    Must not conflict with defaults: /ndl /TEE /Bytes /NC /nfl /Log

    .PARAMETER ProgressID
    When specified (>=0) will use this identifier for the progress bar

    .PARAMETER ParentProgressID
    When specified (>= 0) will use this identifier as the parent ID for progress bars
    so that they appear nested which allows for usage in more complex scripts.

    .OUTPUTS
    Returns an object with the status of final copy.
    REMINDER: Any error level below 8 can be considered a success by RoboCopy.

    .EXAMPLE
    C:\PS> .\Copy-ItemWithProgress c:\Src d:\Dest

    Copy the contents of the c:\Src directory to a directory d:\Dest
    Without the /e or /mir switch, only files from the root of c:\src are copied.

    .EXAMPLE
    C:\PS> .\Copy-ItemWithProgress '"c:\Src Files"' d:\Dest /mir /xf *.log -Verbose

    Copy the contents of the 'c:\Name with Space' directory to a directory d:\Dest
    /mir and /XF parameters are passed to robocopy, and script is run verbose

    .LINK
    https://keithga.wordpress.com/2014/06/23/copy-itemwithprogress

    .NOTES
    By Keith S. Garner (KeithGa@KeithGa.com) - 6/23/2014
    With inspiration by Trevor Sullivan @pcgeek86
    Tweaked by Justin Marshall - 02/20/2020

    #>

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Source,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Destination,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$FilesToCopy="*.*",
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] 
        [string[]] $RobocopyArgs,
        [int]$ParentProgressID=-1,
        [int]$ProgressID=-1
    )

    #handle spaces and trailing slashes
    $SourceDir = '"{0}"' -f ($Source -replace "\\+$","")
    $TargetDir = '"{0}"' -f ($Destination -replace "\\+$","")


    $ScanLog  = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
    $RoboLog  = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
    $ScanArgs = @($SourceDir,$TargetDir,$FilesToCopy) + $RobocopyArgs + "/ndl /TEE /bytes /Log:$ScanLog /nfl /L".Split(" ")
    $RoboArgs = @($SourceDir,$TargetDir,$FilesToCopy) + $RobocopyArgs + "/ndl /TEE /bytes /Log:$RoboLog /NC".Split(" ")

    # Launch Robocopy Processes
    write-verbose ("Robocopy Scan:`n" + ($ScanArgs -join " "))
    write-verbose ("Robocopy Full:`n" + ($RoboArgs -join " "))
    $ScanRun = start-process robocopy -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList $ScanArgs
    try
    {
        $RoboRun = start-process robocopy -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList $RoboArgs
        try
        {
            # Parse Robocopy "Scan" pass
            $ScanRun.WaitForExit()
            $LogData = get-content $ScanLog
            if ($ScanRun.ExitCode -ge 8)
            {
                $LogData|out-string|Write-Error
                throw "Robocopy $($ScanRun.ExitCode)"
            }
            $FileSize = [regex]::Match($LogData[-4],".+:\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)").Groups[2].Value
            write-verbose ("Robocopy Bytes: $FileSize `n" +($LogData -join "`n"))
            #determine progress parameters
            $ProgressParms=@{}
            if ($ParentProgressID -ge 0) {
                $ProgressParms['ParentID']=$ParentProgressID
            }
            if ($ProgressID -ge 0) {
                $ProgressParms['ID']=$ProgressID
            } else {
                $ProgressParms['ID']=$RoboRun.Id
            }
            # Monitor Full RoboCopy
            while (!$RoboRun.HasExited)
            {
                $LogData = get-content $RoboLog
                $Files = $LogData -match "^\s*(\d+)\s+(\S+)"
                if ($null -ne $Files )
                {
                    $copied = ($Files[0..($Files.Length-2)] | ForEach-Object {$_.Split("`t")[-2]} | Measure-Object -sum).Sum
                    if ($LogData[-1] -match "(100|\d?\d\.\d)\%")
                    {
                        write-progress Copy -ParentID $ProgressParms['ID'] -percentComplete $LogData[-1].Trim("% `t") $LogData[-1]
                        $Copied += $Files[-1].Split("`t")[-2] /100 * ($LogData[-1].Trim("% `t"))
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        write-progress Copy -ParentID $ProgressParms['ID'] -Complete
                    }
                    write-progress ROBOCOPY  -PercentComplete ($Copied/$FileSize*100) $Files[-1].Split("`t")[-1] @ProgressParms
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (!$RoboRun.HasExited) {Write-Warning "Terminating copy process with ID $($RoboRun.Id)..."; $RoboRun.Kill() ; }
            $RoboRun.WaitForExit()
            # Parse full RoboCopy pass results, and cleanup
            (get-content $RoboLog)[-11..-2] | out-string | Write-Verbose
            remove-item $RoboLog
            write-output ([PSCustomObject]@{ ExitCode = $RoboRun.ExitCode })

        }
    } finally {
        if (!$ScanRun.HasExited) {Write-Warning "Terminating scan process with ID $($ScanRun.Id)..."; $ScanRun.Kill() }
        $ScanRun.WaitForExit()

        remove-item $ScanLog
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This recursive function copies files and directories recursively from source path to destination path
If file already exists on destination path, it copies them only with newer files.

```
Function Copy-FilesBitsTransfer(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$sourcePath, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$destinationPath, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][bool]$createRootDirectory = $true)
{
    $item = Get-Item $sourcePath
    $itemName = Split-Path $sourcePath -leaf
    if (!$item.PSIsContainer){ #Item Is a file

        $clientFileTime = Get-Item $sourcePath | select LastWriteTime -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime

        if (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationPath\$itemName)){
            Start-BitsTransfer -Source $sourcePath -Destination $destinationPath -Description "$sourcePath >> $destinationPath" -DisplayName "Copy Template file" -Confirm:$false
            if (!$?){
                return $false
            }
        }
        else{
            $serverFileTime = Get-Item $destinationPath\$itemName | select LastWriteTime -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime

            if ($serverFileTime -lt $clientFileTime)
            {
                Start-BitsTransfer -Source $sourcePath -Destination $destinationPath -Description "$sourcePath >> $destinationPath" -DisplayName "Copy Template file" -Confirm:$false
                if (!$?){
                    return $false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{ #Item Is a directory
        if ($createRootDirectory){
            $destinationPath = "$destinationPath\$itemName"
            if (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationPath -PathType Container)){
                if (Test-Path -Path $destinationPath -PathType Leaf){ #In case item is a file, delete it.
                    Remove-Item -Path $destinationPath
                }

                New-Item -ItemType Directory $destinationPath | Out-Null
                if (!$?){
                    return $false
                }

            }
        }
        Foreach ($fileOrDirectory in (Get-Item -Path "$sourcePath\*"))
        {
            $status = Copy-FilesBitsTransfer $fileOrDirectory $destinationPath $true
            if (!$status){
                return $false
            }
        }
    }

    return $true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sean Kearney from the [Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/12/20/build-a-better-copy-item-cmdlet-2/) has a solution I found works pretty nicely.

```
Function Copy-WithProgress
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
            Position=0)]
        $Source,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
            Position=0)]
        $Destination
    )

    $Source=$Source.tolower()
    $Filelist=Get-Childitem "$Source" –Recurse
    $Total=$Filelist.count
    $Position=0

    foreach ($File in $Filelist)
    {
        $Filename=$File.Fullname.tolower().replace($Source,'')
        $DestinationFile=($Destination+$Filename)
        Write-Progress -Activity "Copying data from '$source' to '$Destination'" -Status "Copying File $Filename" -PercentComplete (($Position/$total)*100)
        Copy-Item $File.FullName -Destination $DestinationFile
        $Position++
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
Copy-WithProgress -Source $src -Destination $dest
```

Comment: This will report the number of files copied in `$Filelist`, whereas the question is asking how to report the progress of copying a single file (i.e. the count of bytes/blocks copied thus far).  If this code were used to copy a single, large file it would give no indication how far the copy operation has progressed within that file.  From the question body: "There are solutions out there to use Write-Progress in conjunction with looping to copy many files and display progress. However I can't seem to find anything that would show progress of a single file."

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but I thought it might help others.
The solution with FileStreams is elegant and it works, but very slow.
I think using other programs, like robocopy.exe defeats powershell's purpose.
That was even one of the motivations in the Monad manifest.
So I cracked open the Copy-Item cmdlet from Microsoft.PowerShell.Management, and at the end, it calls CopyFileEx, from kernel32.dll.

On CopyFileEx signature, there's a parameter that accepts a callback to provide progress information.
On [pinvoke.net](https://pinvoke.net) there's a great example on how to marshal this function and the callback into a delegate.
I modified slightly so we can provide the delegate from the PS script itself.

And believe me when I say this.
I was not expecting this to work :D (I literally jumped from the chair).

And it's considerably faster.
Here's the code:

```
function Copy-File {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 1)]
        [string]$Destination
    )

    $signature = @'
    namespace Utilities {

        using System;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    
        public class FileSystem {
            
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            static extern bool CopyFileEx(
                string lpExistingFileName,
                string lpNewFileName,
                CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine,
                IntPtr lpData,
                ref Int32 pbCancel,
                CopyFileFlags dwCopyFlags
            );
        
            delegate CopyProgressResult CopyProgressRoutine(
            long TotalFileSize,
            long TotalBytesTransferred,
            long StreamSize,
            long StreamBytesTransferred,
            uint dwStreamNumber,
            CopyProgressCallbackReason dwCallbackReason,
            IntPtr hSourceFile,
            IntPtr hDestinationFile,
            IntPtr lpData);
        
            int pbCancel;
        
            public enum CopyProgressResult : uint
            {
                PROGRESS_CONTINUE = 0,
                PROGRESS_CANCEL = 1,
                PROGRESS_STOP = 2,
                PROGRESS_QUIET = 3
            }
        
            public enum CopyProgressCallbackReason : uint
            {
                CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED = 0x00000000,
                CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH = 0x00000001
            }
        
            [Flags]
            enum CopyFileFlags : uint
            {
                COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS = 0x00000001,
                COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE = 0x00000002,
                COPY_FILE_OPEN_SOURCE_FOR_WRITE = 0x00000004,
                COPY_FILE_ALLOW_DECRYPTED_DESTINATION = 0x00000008
            }
        
            public void CopyWithProgress(string oldFile, string newFile, Func<long, long, long, long, uint, CopyProgressCallbackReason, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, CopyProgressResult> callback)
            {
                CopyFileEx(oldFile, newFile, new CopyProgressRoutine(callback), IntPtr.Zero, ref pbCancel, CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE);
            }
        }
    }
'@

    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $signature

    [Func[long, long, long, long, System.UInt32, Utilities.FileSystem+CopyProgressCallbackReason, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, Utilities.FileSystem+CopyProgressResult]]$copyProgressDelegate = {

        param($total, $transfered, $streamSize, $streamByteTrans, $dwStreamNumber, $reason, $hSourceFile, $hDestinationFile, $lpData)

        Write-Progress -Activity "Copying file" -Status "$Path ~> $Destination. $([Math]::Round(($transfered/1KB), 2))KB/$([Math]::Round(($total/1KB), 2))KB." -PercentComplete (($transfered / $total) * 100)
    }

    $fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($Path)
    $destFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($Destination)
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($destFileName) -or $destFileName -notlike '*.*') {
        if ($Destination.EndsWith('\')) {
            $destFullName = "$Destination$fileName"
        }
        else {
            $destFullName = "$Destination\$fileName"
        }
    }

    $wrapper = New-Object Utilities.FileSystem
    $wrapper.CopyWithProgress($Path, $destFullName, $copyProgressDelegate)
}
```

Hope it helps.
Happy scripting!

**Update:**

Same thing, but using CopyFile2.

```
try {
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
namespace Utilities {
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public delegate COPYFILE2_MESSAGE_ACTION CopyFile2ProgressRoutine(
        [In] COPYFILE2_MESSAGE pMessage,
        [In, Optional] IntPtr pvCallbackContext
    );

    [Flags]
    public enum CopyFlags : uint {
        COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS = 0x00000001,
        COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE = 0x00000002,
        COPY_FILE_OPEN_SOURCE_FOR_WRITE = 0x00000004,
        COPY_FILE_ALLOW_DECRYPTED_DESTINATION = 0x00000008,
        COPY_FILE_COPY_SYMLINK = 0x00000800,
        COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING = 0x00001000,
        COPY_FILE_REQUEST_SECURITY_PRIVILEGES = 0x00002000,
        COPY_FILE_RESUME_FROM_PAUSE = 0x00004000,
        COPY_FILE_NO_OFFLOAD = 0x00040000,
        COPY_FILE_REQUEST_COMPRESSED_TRAFFIC = 0x10000000
    }
    
    public enum COPYFILE2_MESSAGE_ACTION : uint {
        COPYFILE2_PROGRESS_CONTINUE,
        COPYFILE2_PROGRESS_CANCEL,
        COPYFILE2_PROGRESS_STOP,
        COPYFILE2_PROGRESS_QUIET,
        COPYFILE2_PROGRESS_PAUSE
    }

    public enum COPYFILE2_MESSAGE_TYPE : uint {
        COPYFILE2_CALLBACK_NONE,
        COPYFILE2_CALLBACK_CHUNK_STARTED,
        COPYFILE2_CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED,
        COPYFILE2_CALLBACK_STREAM_STARTED,
        COPYFILE2_CALLBACK_STREAM_FINISHED,
        COPYFILE2_CALLBACK_POLL_CONTINUE,
        COPYFILE2_CALLBACK_ERROR,
        COPYFILE2_CALLBACK_MAX
    }

    public enum COPYFILE2_COPY_PHASE : uint {
        COPYFILE2_PHASE_NONE,
        COPYFILE2_PHASE_PREPARE_SOURCE,
        COPYFILE2_PHASE_PREPARE_DEST,
        COPYFILE2_PHASE_READ_SOURCE,
        COPYFILE2_PHASE_WRITE_DESTINATION,
        COPYFILE2_PHASE_SERVER_COPY,
        COPYFILE2_PHASE_NAMEGRAFT_COPY,
        COPYFILE2_PHASE_MAX
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ULARGE_INTEGER {
        public Int64 QuadPart;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct _ChunkStarted {
        public uint          dwStreamNumber;
        public uint          dwReserved;
        public IntPtr         hSourceFile;
        public IntPtr         hDestinationFile;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliChunkNumber;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliChunkSize;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliStreamSize;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliTotalFileSize;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct _ChunkFinished {
        public uint          dwStreamNumber;
        public uint          dwFlags;
        public IntPtr         hSourceFile;
        public IntPtr         hDestinationFile;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliChunkNumber;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliChunkSize;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliStreamSize;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliStreamBytesTransferred;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliTotalFileSize;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliTotalBytesTransferred;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct _StreamStarted {
        public uint          dwStreamNumber;
        public uint          dwReserved;
        public IntPtr         hSourceFile;
        public IntPtr         hDestinationFile;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliStreamSize;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliTotalFileSize;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct _StreamFinished {
        public uint          dwStreamNumber;
        public uint          dwReserved;
        public IntPtr         hSourceFile;
        public IntPtr         hDestinationFile;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliStreamSize;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliStreamBytesTransferred;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliTotalFileSize;
        public ULARGE_INTEGER uliTotalBytesTransferred;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct _PollContinue {
        public uint dwReserved;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct _Error {
        COPYFILE2_COPY_PHASE CopyPhase;
        uint                dwStreamNumber;
        IntPtr              hrFailure;
        uint                dwReserved;
        ULARGE_INTEGER       uliChunkNumber;
        ULARGE_INTEGER       uliStreamSize;
        ULARGE_INTEGER       uliStreamBytesTransferred;
        ULARGE_INTEGER       uliTotalFileSize;
        ULARGE_INTEGER       uliTotalBytesTransferred;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct COPYFILE2_MESSAGE {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public COPYFILE2_MESSAGE_TYPE Type;

        [FieldOffset(1)]
        public uint dwPadding;

        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public _ChunkStarted ChunkStarted;

        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public _ChunkFinished ChunkFinished;

        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public _StreamStarted StreamStarted;

        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public _StreamFinished StreamFinished;

        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public _PollContinue PollContinue;

        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public _Error Error;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct COPYFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS {
        public uint dwSize;
        public CopyFlags dwCopyFlags;
        public bool pfCancel;
        public CopyFile2ProgressRoutine pProgressRoutine;
        public IntPtr pvCallbackContext;
    }

    public class FileSystem {

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern uint CopyFile2(
            string pwszExistingFileName,
            string pwszNewFileName,
            COPYFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS pExtendedParameters
        );

        public static void CopyFileEx(string filePath, string destination, Func<COPYFILE2_MESSAGE, IntPtr, COPYFILE2_MESSAGE_ACTION> callback) {
            COPYFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS extParams = new();
            extParams.dwSize = Convert.ToUInt32(Marshal.SizeOf(extParams));
            extParams.dwCopyFlags = CopyFlags.COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING | CopyFlags.COPY_FILE_COPY_SYMLINK;
            extParams.pProgressRoutine = new CopyFile2ProgressRoutine(callback);
            extParams.pvCallbackContext = IntPtr.Zero;

            uint result = CopyFile2(filePath, destination, extParams);
            if (result != 0)
                throw new SystemException(result.ToString());
        }
    }
}
'@
}
catch { }

[Func[
    Utilities.COPYFILE2_MESSAGE,
    IntPtr,
    Utilities.COPYFILE2_MESSAGE_ACTION
]]$delegate = {

    param([Utilities.COPYFILE2_MESSAGE]$message, $extArgs, $result)

    if ($message.Type -eq [Utilities.COPYFILE2_MESSAGE_TYPE]::COPYFILE2_CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED) {
        Write-Progress -Activity 'Copying file.' -Status 'Copying...' -PercentComplete (($message.ChunkFinished.uliTotalFileSize.QuadPart / $message.ChunkFinished.uliStreamBytesTransferred.QuadPart) * 100)
    }
}

if (Test-Path -Path C:\CopyFile2TestDestination -PathType Container) { [void](mkdir C:\CopyFile2TestDestination) }
[Utilities.FileSystem]::CopyFileEx('C:\superTest.dat', 'C:\CopyFile2TestDestination\superTestCopy.dat', $delegate)
```

Comment: Looks great, but i just learned about CopyFileEx not supporting the source being a directory.  Is CopyFile2 any better in this regard?

Comment: Indeed, my original idea is to manage directories directly, using either 'New-Item' or 'System.IO.Directory'. CopyFile2 does not support a progress callback, but it's a good source.

Comment: Your code is the best example I've found for CopyFileEx - I do appreciate it!  Looks like [CopyFile2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile2) supports a [progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-copyfile2_extended_parameters) [routine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nc-winbase-pcopyfile2_progress_routine).

I might try and call CopyFileEx recursively whenever I detect a directory as a source item, and keep drilling down. Hopefully won't hit any limitations.

Comment: Interesting! I'll have to try it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes!!! It werkss.
https://github.com/FranciscoNabas/PowerShellPublic/blob/main/CopyFile2.ps1
For some weird reason ChunkFinished.uliTotalBytesTransferred and ChunkFinished.uliTotalFileSize are backwards. I must have missed something while marshaling the union.

Comment: The first script works brilliantly for me!  (The CopyFile2 version bombed out for me, but I may have been holding my mouse wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Trevor Sullivan has a write-up on how to add a command called [Copy-ItemWithProgress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21209726/62857) to PowerShell on Robocopy.