# Recursive search through directory tree for files in date range - getting "Batch Recursion exceeds stack limits" error

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion, stack, exceed

I am a newby to dos batch scripts.  I pieced together several code snippets, and with a few modifications, got my script to work for a small directory.  It recurses through a directory tree, counts the number of files within a date range passed in as parameters, and then writes an output file report.

It works fine for a small directory structure, but if it has to recurse through more than a few hundred folders, then it aborts with the "Batch recursion exceeds stack limits" error.

I understand from this site that recursive loops aren't very efficient and once I've put a certain amount of data on the stack I'm toast.  I have looked on this site and elsewhere for help.  Most of the advice is to write a more efficient program, but I'm not certain of how to do that.  Any help would be appreciated.  I need to increase the efficiency by an order of magnitude, as the directory structures I need this for will have thousands of folders.  Here is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
pushd %1

REM This program takes three parameters <starting directory> <startdate> <enddate>
REM The startdate and endate should be in format: mm/dd/yyyy
REM The program will recursively look through all directories and sub-directories
REM from the given <starting directory> and count up the number of files written
REM within the date range from <startdate> until <endate>
REM It will then write out a RetentionReport_<date>_<time>.txt file that lists
REM one line showing the <startdate> <enddate> and the # of files found.

REM If you don't pass in all three arguments it will let you know and then exit.

REM You need to set your TESTDIR below to a hardpath location for the writing
REM of temporary files and writing of the Reports

REM There is one .tmp file created during processing and then deleted.
REM To prevent the .tmp file being deleted you can comment out the second
REM instance of this line by adding a REM in front of it:
REM if exist %TESTDIR%*.tmp del %TESTDIR%*.tmp

REM If you want to print out a .tmp file that lists the files counted for the
REM period given then you could remove the REM from in front of the following
REM line in the below code: echo %%~tF   %%F>> %TESTDIR%MONTH_files.tmp


set "TAB=   "
set "MONTHTOTAL=0"
set hr=%time:~0,2%
if "%hr:~0,1%" equ " " set hr=0%hr:~1,1%
set "TESTDIR=C:\TEST\"

if "%~2" == "" (
    echo Please pass in arguments for starting directory, startdate, and enddate.
    echo startdate and endate should be in the format mm/dd/yyyy
    exit/b
)
if "%~3" == "" (
    echo Please pass in arguments for starting directory, startdate, and enddate.
    echo startdate and endate should be in the format mm/dd/yyyy
    exit/b
)


set "startdate=%~2"
set "enddate=%~3"

if exist %TESTDIR%*.tmp del %TESTDIR%*.tmp
call :run >nul
FOR /F %%i IN (%TESTDIR%temp_TotalByDir.tmp) DO set /a MONTHTOTAL=!MONTHTOTAL!+%%i
echo %startdate%%TAB%%enddate%%TAB%!MONTHTOTAL! >> %TESTDIR%RetentionReport_%date:~-    4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt
if exist %TESTDIR%*.tmp del %TESTDIR%*.tmp
exit /b

:run
for %%F in (.) do echo %%~fF
endlocal

:listFolder
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "ADD=0"

for %%F in (*) do ( 
  if %%~tF GEQ %startdate% (
      if %%~tF LEQ %enddate% (
          REM echo %%~tF   %%F>> %TESTDIR%MONTH_files.tmp
      set /a ADD+=1
      )
  )
)

echo !ADD! >> %TESTDIR%temp_TotalByDir.tmp

for /d %%F in (*) do (
  pushd "%%F"
  call :listFolder
  popd
)

endlocal

exit /b
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Comment: So appreciative for all of the responses....just seeing them now...I will dig into the responses tonight and tomorrow morning and get back to you....thanks!

Comment: A lot of geniuses on this site.  @dbenham and magoo both had a lot too teach me, and both of their versions worked beautifully.  Thanks guys!  I am going to mark dbenham for the answer since his won a speedrace against 100,000 files by 2 minutes, but thanks to both of you big time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have other problems besides recursion stack limits. The IF statement does not know how to compare dates. It only knows strings and numbers. In order to properly compare dates you must reformat the date to be in YYYYMMDD format.

Your timestamp information for use in the output file name should be collected all at once. Your existing code gets the hour at the beginning of the process, and the date, minutes and seconds at the end of the process. Not good. There could be a significant time gap between the start and end times.

Batch has two types of recursion errors:

1) Only 31 SETLOCAL levels within one CALL level.

2) A variable number of recursive CALLs allowed, depending on Windows version, machine memory, ...

There is no way to increase the size of the stack. If you get a recursion error, you must look for ways to reduce the amount of recursion. In your case, you can simply let FOR /R do all the recursion for you!

I modified the script such that the list of files is generated if a 4th argument is passed. I also incorporated the timestamp into file list file name.

The code assumes your machine's file date/time value starts with MM/DD/YYYY. The code will have to be modified if it does not.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

REM This program takes three parameters <starting directory> <startdate> <enddate>
REM The startdate and endate should be in format: mm/dd/yyyy
REM The program will recursively look through all directories and sub-directories
REM from the given <starting directory> and count up the number of files written
REM within the date range from <startdate> until <endate>
REM It will then write out a RetentionReport_<date>_<time>.txt file that lists
REM one line showing the <startdate> <enddate> and the # of files found.

REM If you don't pass in all three arguments it will let you know and then exit.

REM You need to set your TESTDIR below to a hardpath location for the writing
REM of the Reports

REM If you want to print out a .tmp file that lists the files counted for the
REM period given then you can pass in a 4th argument with any value

if "%~3" == "" (
  echo Please pass in arguments for starting directory, startdate, and enddate.
  echo startdate and endate should be in the format mm/dd/yyyy
  exit/b
)

set "TAB=   "
set "TESTDIR=D:\TEST\"

set "startdate=%~2"
set "start=%startdate:~-4%%startdate:~0,2%%startdate:~3,2%"
set "enddate=%~3"
set "end=%enddate:~-4%%enddate:~0,2%%enddate:~3,2%"

set "timestamp=%date:~-4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%"
set "timestamp=%timestamp: =0%"

for /r "%~1" %%F in (*) do (
  set "dt=%%~tF"
  set "dt=!dt:~6,4!!dt:~0,2!!dt:~3,2!"
  if !dt! geq %start% if !dt! leq %end% (
    if "%~4" neq "" (echo %%~tF   %%F) >>"%TESTDIR%MONTH_files_%timestamp%.tmp"
    set /a cnt+=1
  )
)

(echo %startdate%%TAB%%enddate%%TAB%%cnt%) >>"%testdir%RetentionReport_%timestamp%.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

The *number of folders* have no relation with the *recursive level*. If each *directory level* is processed with a recursive call, the maximum deep of recursive calls should be 10 or 11 in a very large tree. I suggest you to start with [the code below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314433/batch-file-to-copy-directories-recursively/13316123#13316123) as base and modify it for your needs:

```
@echo off
call :treeProcess
goto :eof

:treeProcess
rem Do whatever you want here over the files of this subdir, for example:
copy *.* C:\dest\dir
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    cd %%d
    call :treeProcess
    cd ..
)
exit /b
```

**EDIT**

I reviewed your code and the only strange point is the `endlocal` command placed below `:run` label. I think that at this point all previously defined variables are released, with unpredictable results. This is a simpler version of your code that I think should correctly work:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "TAB=   "
set "MONTHTOTAL=0"
set hr=%time:~0,2%
if "%hr:~0,1%" equ " " set hr=0%hr:~1,1%
set "TESTDIR=C:\TEST\"

set "startdate=%~2"
set "enddate=%~3"

if exist %TESTDIR%*.tmp del %TESTDIR%*.tmp
call :run >nul
FOR /F %%i IN (%TESTDIR%temp_TotalByDir.tmp) DO set /a MONTHTOTAL+=%%i
echo %startdate%%TAB%%enddate%%TAB%%MONTHTOTAL% >> %TESTDIR%RetentionReport_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt
if exist %TESTDIR%*.tmp del %TESTDIR%*.tmp
exit /b

:run

:listFolder

set "ADD=0"

for %%F in (*) do ( 
   if %%~tF GEQ %startdate% (
      if %%~tF LEQ %enddate% (
         REM echo %%~tF   %%F>> %TESTDIR%MONTH_files.tmp
         set /a ADD+=1
      )
   )
)

echo %ADD% >> %TESTDIR%temp_TotalByDir.tmp

for /d %%F in (*) do (
  cd "%%F"
  call :listFolder
  cd ..
)
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is caused by calling `:listFolder` within `:listFolder`.

```dos
@echo off
setlocal

REM This program takes three parameters <starting directory> <startdate> <enddate>
REM The startdate and endate should be in format: mm/dd/yyyy
REM The program will recursively look through all directories and sub-directories
REM from the given <starting directory> and count up the number of files written
REM within the date range from <startdate> until <endate>
REM It will then write out a RetentionReport_<date>_<time>.txt file that lists
REM one line showing the <startdate> <enddate> and the # of files found.

REM If you don't pass in all three arguments it will let you know and then exit.

REM You need to set your TESTDIR below to a hardpath location for the writing
REM of temporary files and writing of the Reports

REM There is one .tmp file created during processing and then deleted.
REM To prevent the .tmp file being deleted you can comment out the second
REM instance of this line by adding a REM in front of it:
REM if exist %TESTDIR%*.tmp del %TESTDIR%*.tmp

REM If you want to print out a .tmp file that lists the files counted for the
REM period given then you could remove the REM from in front of the following
REM line in the below code: echo %%~tF   %%F>> %TESTDIR%MONTH_files.tmp


set "startdate=%~2"
set "enddate=%~3"
IF DEFINED startdate IF DEFINED enddate GOTO parmsok
echo Please pass in arguments for starting directory, startdate, and enddate.
echo startdate and endate should be in the format mm/dd/yyyy
GOTO :eof

:parmsok
CALL :convdate startdate "%startdate%"
CALL :convdate enddate "%enddate%"
set "TAB=   "
set /a MONTHTOTAL=0
set /a GRANDTOTAL=0
set "TESTDIR=C:\TEST\"

if exist %TESTDIR%*.tmp del %TESTDIR%*.tmp
pushd %1
REM call :run >NUL
call :run
popd
FOR /F %%i IN (%TESTDIR%temp_TotalByDir.tmp) DO set /a MONTHTOTAL+=%%i
set hr=%time:~0,2%
set hr=%hr: =0%
echo %startdate%%TAB%%enddate%%TAB%%MONTHTOTAL% >> "%TESTDIR%RetentionReport_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt"
ECHO %grandtotal%
if exist %TESTDIR%*.tmp del %TESTDIR%*.tmp
GOTO :eof 

:run
for /d /r . %%T in (.) do (
  pushd "%%T"
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   call :listFolder
   POPD
  )
)
GOTO :eof

:listFolder
set /a ADD=0

for %%F in (*) do (
  CALL :convdate filedate "%%~tF"
  CALL :compdate
  IF DEFINED inrange (
  REM  echo %%~tF   %%F>> %TESTDIR%MONTH_files.txt
    set /a ADD+=1
    SET /a GRANDTOTAL+=1
  )
)
echo %ADD% >> %TESTDIR%temp_TotalByDir.tmp

GOTO :EOF

:: Convert date in %2 to yyyymmdd in %1

:convdate
SET "$1=%~2"
:: replace any space with 0
SET $1=%$1: =0%
:: convert date format. I use dd/mm/yyyy.
SET %1=%$1:~6,4%%$1:~3,2%%$1:~0,2%
:: version for mm/dd/yyyy.
REM SET %1=%$1:~3,2%%$1:~6,4%%$1:~0,2%
GOTO :EOF

:: Set Inrange iff date is in range

:compdate
SET "inrange="
if %filedate% GEQ %startdate% if %filedate% LEQ %enddate% SET inrange=Y
GOTO :eof
```

Interesting exercise.

A few points:

Delayed expansion is not necessary.

Assign the daterange variables. Only if both exist proceed else error message and exit.

Set common variables. Note the syntax `set "var=string"` is designed to ensure that trailing spaces on the line are not included in the value assigned. The `set /a` syntax to assign an numeric value is immune to trailing spaces.

`PUSHD` your target directory; POPD after processing to return to your original.

I removed the `>nul` from the `call :run` to allow kbd interrupt

The syntax `set "var=%var: =0%" replaces spaces with zeroes.

I moved the setting of `hr` to just before the `RetentionReport` was generated in case the run-time caused the hour to change.

Your original (optional) filelist was written to a `.tmp` file which would have been deleted, so I changed it to a `.txt` file.

`for /d /r` does a recursive directory-name scan, including the current directory in the form shown.

if `pushd` fails (it did on directorynames containing <kbd>!</kbd> with `delayedexpansion`) then it is ineffective, so only if `errorlevel` is 0 should the `call` and `popd` be executed.

listfolder examines exactly one directory - the current.

The dates need to be converted to yyyymmdd form for proper comparison. This need to be performed on the supplied dates just the once (no point in perpetually re-converting them within the loop) which is done at the start.

The main use for `delayedexpansion` is to access the value of a variable where the value chages within a loop; however, the `if defined` test (and `if exist` and `if errorlevel n`) acts on the run-time value, not the parse-time value. Hence this method avoids the use of `delayedexpansion` - for a demonstration, if nothing else.

Final remarks: Executing an `xcopy /L /D` with an appropriate date and to an empty directory would list the files that were generated on and after the selected date. Therefore, running `XCOPY /L /D` to an empty directory for the two dates could be coaxed to produce a filecount; #earlier - #later = #between.

The count of files (=lines) in `MONTH_files.txt` would be equal to the `GRANDTOTAL` (and `MONTHTOTAL`) - but would be a good idea to delete `MONTH_files.txt` at the start (no longer a `.tmp` file...)