# how base option affects gulp.src & gulp.dest

Tags: gulp

I encountered an issue trying to copy a set of files and when calling .dest('some folder') the entire folder structure was lost.

I searched and found an answer suggesting that I should provide `{base:'.'}` as an option on my call to `gulp.src(...)` to resolve this issue.

The [documentation for gulp.src options](https://github.com/arvindr21/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#options) only says that its options are:

> Options to pass to node-glob through glob-stream.

Looking into [node-glob documentation for its options](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#options) base is not listed there at all.
And the [glob-stream options documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/glob-stream#options) only states that

> "the Default is everything before a glob starts (see glob-parent)"

So no much help here either.

So, what effect does the `base` option passed to `gulp.src` have on the viny6l files in the created stream and how does it effect the `gulp.dest` command ?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

(You're not looking at the official gulp documentation. http://github.com/arvindr21/gulp is just some guy's fork of the gulpjs github repo. The official repo is http://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/ where the [base option is indeed documented](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/api/concepts.md#glob-base).)

To answer your question:

If you don't specify the `base` option yourself, then everything before the first glob in your `gulp.src()` paths is automatically used as the `base` option and ommitted when writing to the destination folder.

Say you have the following files:

```
some/path/example/app/js/app.js
some/path/example/vendor/js/vendor.js
some/path/example/vendor/lib/js/lib.js
```

And this is your Gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.src('some/path/**/js/*.js')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('output'));
```

In this case everything before the `**` is automatically used as your `base` option. So the above is essentially equivalent to this:

```
gulp.src('some/path/**/js/*.js', {base:'some/path/'})
  .pipe(gulp.dest('output'));
```

What this means is that `some/path/` is stripped from the path of every file that matches the pattern in `gulp.src()`. The resulting structure in the `output` folder looks like this:

```
output/example/app/js/app.js
output/example/vendor/js/vendor.js
output/example/vendor/lib/js/lib.js
```

So a certain part of the directory structure of your source files is indeed lost. How much of your directory structure you lose depends on where the first glob in your `gulp.src()` pattern is.

If you want to avoid this you have to explicitly specify the `base` option:

```
gulp.src('some/path/**/js/*.js', {base:'.'})
  .pipe(gulp.dest('output'));
```

Now `some/path/` will not be stripped from your file paths, resulting in the following folder structure in `output`:

```
output/some/path/example/app/js/app.js
output/some/path/example/vendor/js/vendor.js
output/some/path/example/vendor/lib/js/lib.js
```

**EDIT:** If you pass an array of patterns to `gulp.src()` there's no way to specify a different `base` option for each of the array elements. This for example *won't* work:

```
gulp.src(
  ['source1/examples/**/*.html',
   'source2/examples/**/*.html'],
  { base: ['source1/',    // Doesn't work. 
           'source2/']}   // Needs to be a string.
).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

Instead you have to follow the ["Using multiple sources in one task" recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md). This lets you merge two streams each of which can receive its own `base` option:

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  merge(gulp.src('source1/examples/**/*.html', {base: 'source1/'}),
        gulp.src('source2/examples/**/*.html', {base: 'source2/'}))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: 10x.
do you know What if i Want to specify different base paths to different glob patterns (given in an array)? e.g. if I have ['source1/examples/**/*.html','source2/examples/**/*.html'] and I want to merge all of the exampls to a single '/dist/examples/' folder ?

Comment: Are there any special aspects to this when the source files are in '../somefolder/' (i.e. a sibling folder to that of gulp) and the dest should be in './dest/subfolder'?

Comment: I'm not aware of any gotchas in this case. I would expect it to work like any other relative path.

Comment: This explanation couldn't be better!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info! The link to the 'base' option is broken.