# Gulp, css is saving to dist/css/less, should be dist/css

Tags: gulp

trying to setup my gulp file for a project, I want to compile the less, and then minify it and have it save this to a new folder.

My less file is saved in `app/less/styles.less`, the compiled css file should save to `dist/css/styles.css` but it's saving to `dist/css/less/styles.css`.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
var app = 'app/',
dist = 'dist/',
appStyles = app + '**/*.less';

gulp.task('compilecssremote', function(){
  return gulp.src(appStyles)
  .pipe(plumber({
    errorHandler: onError
  }))
  .pipe(changed(dist)) //must be dist
  .pipe(urladjuster({
    prepend: '/' + project + '/dist/' //based on location of CSS files
  }))
  .pipe(less())
  .pipe(minifycss({keepBreaks: false}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dist + 'css'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior when you use a `gulp.src` like `'app/**/*.less` (aka your `appStyles`) to match source files with paths like `app/less/styles.less`. There are two pieces to understand here:

1. By default everything before the first glob in your `gulp.src` path will be omitted from the output path. In this case that's everything before the `**`, which is to say the `app/`. That's why the your output css file *isn't* going to `'dest/app/…`. (For a more detailed discussion of this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35848322/1241736))
2. The path matched by the first glob and on is preserved in the output path. In this case, that's the `less/` in the matched file `'app/less/styles.less'` (that is, the part of `'app/**/*.less'` represented by `**`). (It's beside the point in the case of your problem, but this feature is very useful for preserving relative file structures.)

Using #1 & #2, one quick fix would be to trim `less/` from the output path by putting it before the first glob in the `gulp.src`. For example, change `appStyles = app + 'less/**/*.less'`.