# gulp same src with multiple destination one with base and one without base

Tags: gulp, glob

i have one gulpfile.js and i need to have the same src glob with multiple destination. But as specified in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845039/how-base-option-affects-gulp-src-gulp-dest) if i specify base then my entire directory starting from `some` are being copied to pubdir which is a problem.

```
var moduleglob = 'some/path/more/' + themeconfig.name + '/' + '**/**/styles/some.scss';

gulp.src(moduleglob,{ base: "./" })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."))

gulp.src(moduleglob)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pubdir))
```

Is there a way to combine above two code into one and while being able to dest to both the correct folders i.e. one with respect to root and one with respect to pubdir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gulp can rename directories with the help of gulp rename plugin.

At first i did not know how it worked but after i understood i got to know that it was very cool plugin actually.

What this plugin does is just renaming the path whatever copied after stripping out the base which was default gulp src and dest behaviour.

So original directory keeps taking `file.base` from all before glob pattern and thus `file.base` was `'some/path/more/' + themeconfig.name` but i needed some modification even after this glob.

I wanted to remove one directory named `web` from the sequence when it drop result on pubdir.

Also, i changed the `file.base` on dest function so it will be not relative to origin there when dropping to pubdir and it will place the directory after removing `web` from sequence.

So above two command can be written like this.

```
gulp.src(moduleglob,{ base: "./" })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."))
        .pipe(rename(function (path) {
            // Updates the object in-place
           let newpathdir = path.dirname.replace('web/','');
           return {
              dirname: newpathdir,
              basename: path.basename,
              extname: path.extname
            };
           
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file){
            file.base = 'some/path/more/' + themeconfig.name;
            return pubdir;
        }))
```