# Octopack won't package ng build output when there are subfolders

Tags: angular, angular-cli, octopus-deploy, octopack

*The gulp-octo version here is 0.0.10, which is no longer the current version. This may or may not apply to the newer versions*

The angular-cli command `ng-build` builds my angular app into a */dist* folder.

I end up with a flat dist folder, containing my js, html, etc files.

```
/dist
  index.html
  inline.js
  [etc]
```

I then can use `gulp-octo` to publish my package to my octopus deploy host, like this:

```
// You need to bump version in package.json and ng build before running this
gulp.task("publish", function() {
    return gulp.src(["dist/**"])
        .pipe(octo.pack())
        .pipe(octo.push(octoConfig));
});
```

Which works.

I then add a file, assetFile.png, to the assets file. This changes what */dist* looks like. It's no longer completely flat:

```
/dist
   /assets
      assetFile.png
  index.html
  inline.js
  [etc]
```

All of a sudden, `gulp publish` fails with this error:

```
λ gulp publish
[11:14:58] Using gulpfile C:\Source\blank-angular-cli-app\gulpfile.js
[11:14:58] Starting 'publish'...
[11:14:58] Packed 'foo.0.0.0.2.tar.gz' with 10 files
C:\Source\blank-angular-cli-app\node_modules\@octopusdeploy\octopackjs\lib\pack.js:26
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Source\blank-angular-cli-app\assets'
    at Error (native)
```

It's clearly unhappy with the */dist* folder containing subfolders (I get the same error if I add folders to the dist after build). But I'm unsure why, and what to do about it.

**What is going on? How do I fix this deployment?**

A minimal example of what's going is on [Github](https://github.com/NathanLBCooper/angular-cli-app/tree/octopus-deploy), which is blank application I created using `ng init` (angular-cli) and then added gulp and octopus to.

Comment: Solved this, will answer shortly. Bug in gulp-octo I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the fix is to add an *assets/* folder at the top level.

```
- assets
    unrelatedDoesntMatter.png
- dist
  - assets
    assetFile.png
[etc]
```

Here is the [commit that fixes my example app](https://github.com/NathanLBCooper/angular-cli-app/commit/4f9a747b16652e4a65deac8fd5debad4a8ce9d0b). This folder doesn't matter, and doesn't get packaged. It just needs to exist. Weird, looks like a bug in gulp-octo.

Answer (score 0):

If you change line 20 in your gulp.js file

```
return gulp.src(["dist/**"])
```

to

```
return gulp.src(["dist/**"], { "base" : "." })
```

it will work.  That second parameter to gulp.src tells it to fetch all of the directories.  See this post for more info: [How do I copy directories recursively with gulp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038014/how-do-i-copy-directories-recursively-with-gulp)