# How to get specific folder and copy its content to another one with gulp

Tags: gulp

Here is what I need to do: for example, I have such directory structure:

```
├── libs
│   ├── folder1
│       ├── font
│           ├── font_name_1
│   ├── folder2
│       ├── fonts 
│           ├── font_name_2
│           ├── font_name_3
```

Is there some possibility to get font/fonts folders content (just content, without parent directories) and move it to another folder?

Something like this:

```
var build = gulp.src(['app/libs/**/font/**/*.*', 'app/libs/**/fonts/**/*.*'])
```

.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts')) but I need to grab only those directories, that are inside of font or fonts directories

Result structure that I need to get:

```
├── fonts
│   ├── font_name_1
│   ├── font_name_2
│   ├── font_name_3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy directories recursively with gulp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038014/how-do-i-copy-directories-recursively-with-gulp)

Comment: There's a  plugin can help u. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten

Comment: Yes! It's working! Thank you, @blackmiaool !