# Typescript does not load handlebar files

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, handlebars.js

I have the following directory structure :

```
src
|- server
  |- myServer.ts
  |- views
    |- myView.hbs
dist
|- server
  |- myServer.js
```

Note that there is no `views` folder in the `dist` folder (where the js sources compiled from typescript are). This is a problem because when I ask for the `../views/selectCoin.hbs` from the javascript, there is nothing.

How do I export `*.hbs` files to javascript when typescript is compiled ?

Comment: why do you use outDir instead of just compiling js files in the same folder? This would completely solve the issue

Comment: Are you using webpack or gulp? Or just pure `tsc` to compile?

Comment: @BrunoLM I am using plain `tsc`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To tell handlebars where the views are you can configure it like this

```
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../../src/server/views'));
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'index',
    extname: 'hbs',
    layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, '../../src/server/views/layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, '../../src/server/views'),
}));
```

So it will look for views in the `src` folder.

---

Another option is to use [`ts-node`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) instead of `node`. With it you don't need to compile your project and you don't need a dist folder, and you can configure it to look directly from where you are:

```
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'index',
    extname: 'hbs',
    layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views'),
}));
```

---

If you want to copy the views to the dist folder you could:

- make a shell script to copy files
- [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) if using webpack
- [copy files with gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27433579/340760) if using gulp

Comment: The `ts-node` is the solution I choose. Didn't test the others. Thansk !