# Alternative for cp -R in windows package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

In my package.json. i have below script

**"assets": "cp -R src/assets/ dist/assets/"**

"**cp -R**" is for linux, help me find the equivalent command for Windows.

Comment: If you want it to run on both platforms, you're better off writing a short Node script that uses the `fs` module to copy the files and changing `npm run assets` to run that instead.

Comment: @JoeClay thanks. But I need a specific command to do in package.json

Comment: So just to be clear - you're fine with the command not working on Linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file to copy directories recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314433/batch-file-to-copy-directories-recursively) - because if so, this probably will answer your question.

Comment: yes. it needs to work on windows only.