# Move up all files one level recursively

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to move up all files one level recursively.

The current folder structure is given bellow

```
D:\_Courses>tree /a
D:.
+---Course 1
|   \---Download
+---Course 2
|   \---Download
+---Course 3
|   \---Download
\---Course 4
    \---Download
```

I want to move all files from "Download" folder to its parent folder.

It means,

All files from "Course 1/Download" should go to "Course 1"

All files from "Course 2/Download" should go to "Course 2"

All files from "Course 3/Download" should go to "Course 3"

All files from "Course 4/Download" should go to "Course 4"

**Problem 1 : Showing a folder that does not exist**

When I used the following command

```
D:\_Courses>FOR /R /D %I IN (Download\) DO @ECHO %I
```

The output is given bellow

```
D:\_Courses\Download\
D:\_Courses\Course 1\Download\
D:\_Courses\Course 1\Download\Download\
D:\_Courses\Course 2\Download\
D:\_Courses\Course 2\Download\Download\
D:\_Courses\Course 3\Download\
D:\_Courses\Course 3\Download\Download\
D:\_Courses\Course 4\Download\
D:\_Courses\Course 4\Download\Download\
```

However, There are no folder called

```
D:\_Courses\Course 1\Download\Download
```

**Problem 2 : Moving to wrong directory**

When I gave the following command

```
D:\_Courses>FOR /R /D %I IN (Download\) DO move "%I"*.* ..
```

All the files from all 4 download folders moved to D:

The output was -

```
D:\_Courses>move "D:\_Courses\Download\"*.* ..
The system cannot find the file specified.

D:\_Courses>move "D:\_Courses\Course 1\Download\"*.* ..
D:\_Courses\Course 1\Download\518057_00_01.mp4
D:\_Courses\Course 1\Download\518057_00_02.mp4
D:\_Courses\Course 1\Download\518057_00_03.mp4
...
       28 file(s) moved.

D:\_Courses>move "D:\_Courses\Course 1\Download\Download\"*.* ..
The system cannot find the file specified.

D:\_Courses>move "D:\_Courses\Course 2\Download\"*.* ..
D:\_Courses\Course 2\Download\486757_00_01.mp4
D:\_Courses\Course 2\Download\486757_00_02.mp4
D:\_Courses\Course 2\Download\486757_00_03.mp4
D:\_Courses\Course 2\Download\486757_00_04.mp4
...
       40 file(s) moved.

D:\_Courses>move "D:\_Courses\Course 2\Download\Download\"*.* ..
The system cannot find the file specified.

D:\_Courses>move "D:\_Courses\Course 3\Download\"*.* ..
D:\_Courses\Course 3\Download\569336_00_01.mp4
D:\_Courses\Course 3\Download\569336_00_02.mp4
D:\_Courses\Course 3\Download\569336_00_03.mp4
D:\_Courses\Course 3\Download\569336_01_01.mp4
D:\_Courses\Course 3\Download\569336_01_02.mp4
...
       19 file(s) moved.

D:\_Courses>move "D:\_Courses\Course 3\Download\Download\"*.* ..
The system cannot find the file specified.

D:\_Courses>move "D:\_Courses\Course 4\Download\"*.* ..
D:\_Courses\Course 4\Download\518056_00_01.mp4
D:\_Courses\Course 4\Download\518056_00_02.mp4
D:\_Courses\Course 4\Download\518056_00_03.mp4
...
       17 file(s) moved.

D:\_Courses>move "D:\_Courses\Course 4\Download\Download\"*.* ..
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: So you want to move all files in all subdirectories to the root directory? or only from a given path?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard this is just the pattern of the folder structure. If a folder named Download exists I want to move it up one level. I am working on it. The following command FOR /R /D %I IN (Download\) DO move "%I"*.* "%I"\.. seems to work. Can you please check and confirm it. Thanks

Comment: ah ok, now I get what you want. Ignore the previous comment

Comment: FOR /R /D %I IN (Download) DO move "%I"\*.* "%I"\..

Comment: What will happen if there are files with identical names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this should do what you want.

```
@echo off
for /r /d %%a in (Download) do (
echo move "%%a\*" "%%a\.."
)
```

Remove echo only once you are happy the results looks fine when echo'd.

Be carefull where you place the batchfile as it will recursively search for all directories named `Download` from the root of the batch file. Also ensure that the batch file does not exist in a directory named `Download`

EDIT: to run from cmdline instead of batch (Ensure you copy the code exactly):

```
for /r /d %a in (Download) do (echo move "%a\*" "%a\..")
```

Comment: for /r /d %a in (Download) do move "%a\*.*" "%a\.." The command works fine but the problem is "D:\_Courses>move "D:\_Courses\Course 4\Download\Download\*.*" "D:\_Courses\Course 4\Download\Download\.."
The system cannot find the file specified." I do not have any folder named "D:\_Courses\Course 4\Download\Download" in my directory structure. What it the problem.

Comment: @blueray yes, if from cmdline, but add %%a if from batch file

Comment: keep in mind you have a `batch-file` tag, hence a `batch-file` answer :)

Comment: @blueray, in your comment above you used, `move "%a` instead of `move "%a\ `!

Comment: @blueray Did you copy my code exactly? Please copy exactly and create a batch file, else if you want to run from cmdline instead, see my edit at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Gerhard, will using `"%a\.*"` not mean that only items beginning with **`.`** will be moved?

Comment: @compo thanks, missed a `*` but made it `\*` which is better written

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13316123/778560):

You may write a recursive algorithm in Batch that gives you exact control of what you do in every nested subdirectory:

```
@echo off
call :treeProcess
goto :eof

:treeProcess
rem Do whatever you want here over the files of this subdir, for example:
move *.* ..
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    cd "%%d"
    call :treeProcess
    cd ..
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Just a heads up; I have a sneaky suspicion, _despite the batch-file tag_, that they are running this directly from a cmd.exe window.

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell script makes use of the directory and file object `Parent` property to copy the files. When you are confident that the correct files will be copied to the correct destination, remove the `WhatIf` from the Move-Item cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path C:/src/t/_Courses -Recurse -Filter 'Download' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $newdir = $_.Parent.FullName
        Get-ChildItem -File -Path $_.FullName |
            ForEach-Object { Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName $newdir -WhatIf }
    }
```

To use this from a cmd shell, put the code above into a file such as movedowns.ps1, then run it.

```
powershell -NoProfile -File movedowns.ps1
```