# Recursive move folders in windows, .bat archive

Tags: batch-file

We have a folder structure like this

```
dir 1
  - dir A
  - dir B
dir 2
  - dir C
dir 3
dir 4
```

Need to move to other directory, all dirs and subdirs, to same level, like this

```
d:\basedir
    dir 1
    dir A
    dir B
    dir 2
    dir C
    dir 3
...
```

I¡ve tried this script but, doesn't works

```
 for %%x in (%*) do (
    move %%x d:\basedir\
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty with the standard methods to solve this type of problems is that they works *top-to-bottom*, that is, they process first the top-most level folder. To correctly solve this problem the folders must be processed *bottom-to-top*: process first the last folders in the tree.

You may use the recursive process of a directory tree described at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314433/batch-file-to-copy-directories-recursively/13316123#13316123)

```
@echo off
cd D:\data\folder
call :treeProcess
goto :eof

:treeProcess
for /D %%d in (*) do (
   cd "%%d"
   call :treeProcess
   cd ..
   move "%%d" D:\basedir
)
exit /b
```

Or, in a simpler way:

```
@echo off
cd D:\data\folder

:treeProcess
for /D %%d in (*) do (
   cd "%%d"
   call :treeProcess
   cd ..
   move "%%d" D:\basedir
)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you move a directory, its sub-directories are no longer available at the source location, so you need to first handle sub-directories before you move their parents:

```cmd
rem /* Iterate through all directories in the tree, and change the default
rem    top-to-bottom order to bottom-to-top order per each sub-branch: */
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%I in ('
    dir /S /B /A:D-H-S "D:\source\*" ^| sort /R
') do (
    move "%%~I" "D:\basedir\"
)
```

---

If you just want the sub- and sub-sub-directories to be moved but not deeper ones, use this code instead:

```cmd
rem // Iterate through immediate child directories:
for /D %%J in ("D:\source\*") do (
    rem // Iterate through grandchild directories:
    for /D %%I in ("%%~J\*") do (
        rem // Move current grandchild directory:
        move "%%~I" "D:\basedir\"
    )
    rem // Move current child directory:
    move "%%~J" "D:\basedir\"
)
```

Comment: Although `dir /S /B /A:D` command gives the folders in "natural" top-down order, sorting this list via `sort /R` command does _NOT_ order the list in "its reverse order", but in _alphabeticall_ reverse order. You may store the list in an array: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /S /B /A:D') do set /A "n+=1" & set "folder[!n!]=%%a"` and then process the array in reverse order: `for /L %%i in (%n%,-1,1) do move "!folder[%%i]!" "D:\basedir\"`

Comment: @Aacini, I agree, my wording was not correct, but the key is bottom-to-top, even though the paths become resorted by reverse alphabetical order; so this approach should work perfectly fine whatsoever, because `a\b\c` comes before  `a\b` which comes before `a`, with `sort /R`…

Comment: You are right: although the order of _the whole list_ is not the reversed of the original list, inside _each subfolder tree_ the names comes in bottom-to-top order.  +1

Answer (score -2):

`FOR /D` should do what you need.

Consider this example:

```
SET "SOURCE_DIR=n:\path\to\data"
FOR /D %%d IN (%SOURCE_DIR%\*.*) DO (
    @ECHO %%~fd
)
```

It returns the absolute path to all the directories underneath `SOURCE_DIR`.

Comment: Not work for me. It move the dirs with subdirs included. i need to move each subdir to top level