# Get the list of files that are getting copied in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am using the PowerShell `Copy-Item` command to copy a directory with files to another location.

I want to display all the files on the console that are getting copied so that I know the status of the copy command.

Comment: This might be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434133/progress-during-large-file-copy-copy-item-write-progress

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you just want to see that in console, use the `-verbose` switch:

```
copy-item -path $from -destination $to -verbose
```

If you want to get a list of files or directories:

```
$files = copy-item -path $from -destination $to -passthru | ?{$_ -is [system.io.fileinfo]}
```

Comment: Another way for testing if an item is a file is to use `? {!$_.PSIsContainer}`.  Also, in V3 you can do this `$files = copy-item $from $to -verbose 4>&1`

Comment: "-verbose" works fine. Thank you. Too bad it's not in the documentation.

Comment: `-Verbose` reports a whole lot of extra information, is there a way to tell it to just output the names of the files copied?

Answer (score 5):

```
$source=ls c:\temp *.*
$i=1
$source| %{
    [int]$percent = $i / $source.count * 100
    Write-Progress -Activity "Copying ... ($percent %)" -status $_  -PercentComplete $percent -verbose
    copy $_.fullName -Destination c:\test 
    $i++
}
```

Comment: This is a really good solution but is not what i need really. The above solution is a little more simple.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to directly output the filenames, you can do it this way:

**With Path**

```
Copy-Item -Path $from -Destination $to –PassThru | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.FullName }
```

**FileName Only**

```
Copy-Item -Path $from -Destination $to –PassThru | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.Name }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to try it this way:

```
(Copy-Item -Verbose C:\SrcDir\*.* c:\DstDir 4>&1).Message
```

Here the messages go to the output stream/pipeline rather than the verbose stream/pipeline and so will work more generally such as in TFS task scripts.