# How to display percentage complete in Robocopy?

Tags: command-line, robocopy

Is there a way to show the percentage completed in Robocopy? I am running with /NDL and /NFL, but I would like to see the overall percentage... is this possible?

Comment: Well over 10k views, and two question up-votes -- sounds about right. Best of luck to you, fellow Googler!

Comment: I haven't tried yet with /ndl and /nfl but it's worth noting that robocopy does give a percentage by default e.g.  `robocopy . .\a blah.big` (that's how to transfer an individual file http://serverfault.com/questions/52983/robocopy-transfer-file-and-not-folder )   and there switch to turn progress bar off says progress bar is default  `/np
Specifies that the progress of the copying operation (the number of files or directories copied so far) will not be displayed.`   But I guess maybe you lose the progess bar with those switches you used

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do so. Instead I use PowerShell to do the copy and track progress.

This might be of use:
[Custom RoboCopy Progress Bar in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883404/custom-robocopy-progress-bar-in-powershell)

Answer (score -1):

Append "/E /V /R:1 /W:5 /ETA" (without quotations) to the end of your command.

For example:

```
robocopy "C:\Test Folder" "\\TestPC\C$\Test Folder" *.* /E /V /R:1 /W:5 /ETA
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Comment: The /ETA just adds text like "16:46 -> 16:46" to the end of each individual file progress, so I'm not sure how this should solve the issue in discussion?

Answer (score -5):

For others who come here from Google and don't normally read the comments, @barlop posted correctly:

> I haven't tried yet with /ndl and /nfl but it's worth noting that robocopy does give a percentage by default e.g.  `robocopy . .\a blah.big` (that's how to transfer an individual file http://serverfault.com/questions/52983/robocopy-transfer-file-and-not-folder )   and there switch to turn progress bar off says progress bar is default  `/np
>   Specifies that the progress of the copying operation (the number of files or directories copied so far) will not be displayed.`   But I guess maybe you lose the progess bar with those switches you used

the default behavior of robocopy is to include percentages. Use /np to not include progress.

Comment: it indicate the per-file percentage, not a percentage for the whole job.