# Get PowerShell to ignore exitcode?

Tags: powershell, exit-code

I am using `robocopy` within PowerShell and `robocopy` returns an exitcode 1 if a file has successfully been copied, which tells PowerShell it failed. Is there a good practice to ignore the error since its not an error?

```
$source = "$env:buildlocation\Reports\$env:ctrelname\DiskImages\DISK1";
$target = "$env:builddestination\$env:ctrelver\$env:ctrelname\Reports";
$robocopyOptions = @('/e', '/r:0', '/np');
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Directory -Attributes !Hidden |
    Sort-Object -Property CreationTime |
    ForEach-Object { & robocopy.exe $source $target $robocopyOptions };
echo $LASTEXITCODE
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883404/custom-robocopy-progress-bar-in-powershell) for instance.

Comment: Why would you need that? Exit codes from external commands don't matter to PowerShell unless you explicitly handle the exit code.

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered the same situation when using **robocopy** from a **PowerShell** script run by **Jenkins**; and in this case, it is **mandatory** to clear **LASTEXITCODE**, because Jenkins checks for it at the end of the job and your job will fail (excluding of course the case where you have another external command called after *robocopy* that clears the last exit code.

I've used this code:

```
$initialExitCode = $global:LASTEXITCODE
Invoke-Expression "robocopy ..."
# See robocopy exit codes: if it's less than 8, there should be no terminal error
if (($initialExitCode -eq 0 -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($initialExitCode)) -and $LASTEXITCODE -le 7) {
    $global:LASTEXITCODE = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated above PowerShell doesn't evaluate the error code of a native command. It only stores it in `$LastExitCode`. Try this simple example:

```
Invoke-Expression 'cmd /c "exit 5"'
```

PowerShell only stores 5 in `$LastExitCode`.