# Process bar Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to copy an HDD to my NAS but I want only the images and videos while conserving the folder and subfolder structure.

I have this code that works but would like to add a progress bar.

**PS :** I am new to powershell so I would love to have some recommendations or a way to improve my code to be more solid, so it doesn't break or something in the middle of copying (I have around 90GB of videos and photos to copy).

Thank you in advance!

**My code :**

```
$sourcePath = 'D:\Users\Dave'
$destPath = 'Z:\Dave Dimov\Photos\HDD 1'
    
Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Recurse -Include '*.png', '*.jpg', '*.jpeg' , '*.mov' , '*.mp4' | Foreach-Object ` {
    
    $destDir = Split-Path ($_.FullName -Replace [regex]::Escape($sourcePath), $destPath)

    if (!(Test-Path $destDir))
    
{
New-Item -ItemType directory $destDir
}

Copy-Item  $_ -Destination $destDir

}
```

Comment: use `robocopy` ... it is designed for what you describe. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you, will check it out and see what I can do. Will update the code if it works or I get suck again, lol

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to help a tad  ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off [Trevor Sullivans "Copy-WithProgress"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883404/custom-robocopy-progress-bar-in-powershell/21209726#21209726) answer, this could work for you.

```
$sourcePath = 'D:\Users\Dave'
$destPath = Test-Path -Path 'Z:\Dave Dimov\Photos\HDD 1'
    if(!$destPath){New-Item -ItemType directory $destDir}
    
$DIRe = Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Filter '*.png', '*.jpg', '*.jpeg' , '*.mov' , '*.mp4' -Recurse 
Copy-WithProgress $DIRe -Destination $destPath -Verbose



function Copy-WithProgress {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [string] $Source
        , [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [string] $Destination
        , [int] $Gap = 200
        , [int] $ReportGap = 2000
    )
    # Define regular expression that will gather number of bytes copied
    $RegexBytes = '(?<=\s+)\d+(?=\s+)';

    #region Robocopy params
    # MIR = Mirror mode
    # NP  = Don't show progress percentage in log
    # NC  = Don't log file classes (existing, new file, etc.)
    # BYTES = Show file sizes in bytes
    # NJH = Do not display robocopy job header (JH)
    # NJS = Do not display robocopy job summary (JS)
    # TEE = Display log in stdout AND in target log file
    $CommonRobocopyParams = '/MIR /NP /NDL /NC /BYTES /NJH /NJS';
    #endregion Robocopy params

    #region Robocopy Staging
    Write-Verbose -Message 'Analyzing robocopy job ...';
    $StagingLogPath = '{0}\temp\{1} robocopy staging.log' -f $env:windir, (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss');

    $StagingArgumentList = '"{0}" "{1}" /LOG:"{2}" /L {3}' -f $Source, $Destination, $StagingLogPath, $CommonRobocopyParams;
    Write-Verbose -Message ('Staging arguments: {0}' -f $StagingArgumentList);
    Start-Process -Wait -FilePath robocopy.exe -ArgumentList $StagingArgumentList -NoNewWindow;
    # Get the total number of files that will be copied
    $StagingContent = Get-Content -Path $StagingLogPath;
    $TotalFileCount = $StagingContent.Count - 1;

    # Get the total number of bytes to be copied
    [RegEx]::Matches(($StagingContent -join "`n"), $RegexBytes) | % { $BytesTotal = 0; } { $BytesTotal += $_.Value; };
    Write-Verbose -Message ('Total bytes to be copied: {0}' -f $BytesTotal);
    #endregion Robocopy Staging

    #region Start Robocopy
    # Begin the robocopy process
    $RobocopyLogPath = '{0}\temp\{1} robocopy.log' -f $env:windir, (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss');
    $ArgumentList = '"{0}" "{1}" /LOG:"{2}" /ipg:{3} {4}' -f $Source, $Destination, $RobocopyLogPath, $Gap, $CommonRobocopyParams;
    Write-Verbose -Message ('Beginning the robocopy process with arguments: {0}' -f $ArgumentList);
    $Robocopy = Start-Process -FilePath robocopy.exe -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Verbose -PassThru -NoNewWindow;
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100;
    #endregion Start Robocopy

    #region Progress bar loop
    while (!$Robocopy.HasExited) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $ReportGap;
        $BytesCopied = 0;
        $LogContent = Get-Content -Path $RobocopyLogPath;
        $BytesCopied = [Regex]::Matches($LogContent, $RegexBytes) | ForEach-Object -Process { $BytesCopied += $_.Value; } -End { $BytesCopied; };
        $CopiedFileCount = $LogContent.Count - 1;
        Write-Verbose -Message ('Bytes copied: {0}' -f $BytesCopied);
        Write-Verbose -Message ('Files copied: {0}' -f $LogContent.Count);
        $Percentage = 0;
        if ($BytesCopied -gt 0) {
           $Percentage = (($BytesCopied/$BytesTotal)*100)
        }
        Write-Progress -Activity Robocopy -Status ("Copied {0} of {1} files; Copied {2} of {3} bytes" -f $CopiedFileCount, $TotalFileCount, $BytesCopied, $BytesTotal) -PercentComplete $Percentage
    }
    #endregion Progress loop

    #region Function output
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        BytesCopied = $BytesCopied;
        FilesCopied = $CopiedFileCount;
    };
    #endregion Function output
}

<#
# 1. TESTING: Generate a random, unique source directory, with some test files in it
$TestSource = '{0}\{1}' -f $env:temp, [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString();
$null = mkdir -Path $TestSource;
# 1a. TESTING: Create some test source files
1..20 | % -Process { Set-Content -Path $TestSource\$_.txt -Value ('A'*(Get-Random -Minimum 10 -Maximum 2100)); };

# 2. TESTING: Create a random, unique target directory
$TestTarget = '{0}\{1}' -f $env:temp, [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString();
$null = mkdir -Path $TestTarget;

# 3. Call the Copy-WithProgress function
Copy-WithProgress -Source $TestSource -Destination $TestTarget -Verbose;

# 4. Add some new files to the source directory
21..40 | % -Process { Set-Content -Path $TestSource\$_.txt -Value ('A'*(Get-Random -Minimum 950 -Maximum 1400)); };

# 5. Call the Copy-WithProgress function (again)
Copy-WithProgress -Source $TestSource -Destination $TestTarget -Verbose;
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me now :

```
    function Copy-WithProgress {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [string] $Source
        , [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [string] $Destination
        , [int] $Gap = 0
        , [int] $ReportGap = 2000
    )
    # Define regular expression that will gather number of bytes copied
    $RegexBytes = '(?<=\s+)\d+(?=\s+)';

    #region Robocopy params
    # MIR = Mirror mode
    # NP  = Don't show progress percentage in log
    # NC  = Don't log file classes (existing, new file, etc.)
    # BYTES = Show file sizes in bytes
    # NJH = Do not display robocopy job header (JH)
    # NJS = Do not display robocopy job summary (JS)
    # TEE = Display log in stdout AND in target log file
    $CommonRobocopyParams =  '*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.mov *.mp4 /MIR /NP /NDL /NC /BYTES /NJH /NJS';
    #endregion Robocopy params

    #region Robocopy Staging
    Write-Verbose -Message 'Analyzing robocopy job ...';
    $StagingLogPath = '{0}\temp\{1} robocopy staging.log' -f $env:windir, (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss');

    $StagingArgumentList = '"{0}" "{1}" /LOG:"{2}" /L {3}' -f $Source, $Destination, $StagingLogPath, $CommonRobocopyParams;
    Write-Verbose -Message ('Staging arguments: {0}' -f $StagingArgumentList);
    Start-Process -Wait -FilePath robocopy.exe -ArgumentList $StagingArgumentList -NoNewWindow;
    # Get the total number of files that will be copied
    $StagingContent = Get-Content -Path $StagingLogPath;
    $TotalFileCount = $StagingContent.Count - 1;

    # Get the total number of bytes to be copied
    [RegEx]::Matches(($StagingContent -join "`n"), $RegexBytes) | % { $BytesTotal = 0; } { $BytesTotal += $_.Value; };
    Write-Verbose -Message ('Total bytes to be copied: {0}' -f $BytesTotal);
    #endregion Robocopy Staging

    #region Start Robocopy
    # Begin the robocopy process
    $RobocopyLogPath = '{0}\temp\{1} robocopy.log' -f $env:windir, (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss');
    $ArgumentList = '"{0}" "{1}" /LOG:"{2}" /ipg:{3} {4}' -f $Source, $Destination, $RobocopyLogPath, $Gap, $CommonRobocopyParams;
    Write-Verbose -Message ('Beginning the robocopy process with arguments: {0}' -f $ArgumentList);
    $Robocopy = Start-Process -FilePath robocopy.exe -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Verbose -PassThru -NoNewWindow;
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100;
    #endregion Start Robocopy

    #region Progress bar loop
    while (!$Robocopy.HasExited) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $ReportGap;
        $BytesCopied = 0;
        $LogContent = Get-Content -Path $RobocopyLogPath;
        $BytesCopied = [Regex]::Matches($LogContent, $RegexBytes) | ForEach-Object -Process { $BytesCopied += $_.Value; } -End { $BytesCopied; };
        $CopiedFileCount = $LogContent.Count - 1;
        Write-Verbose -Message ('Bytes copied: {0}' -f $BytesCopied);
        Write-Verbose -Message ('Files copied: {0}' -f $LogContent.Count);
        $Percentage = 0;
        if ($BytesCopied -gt 0) {
           $Percentage = (($BytesCopied/$BytesTotal)*100)
        }
        Write-Progress -Activity Robocopy -Status ("Copied {0} of {1} files; Copied {2} of {3} bytes" -f $CopiedFileCount, $TotalFileCount, $BytesCopied, $BytesTotal) -PercentComplete $Percentage
    }
    #endregion Progress loop

    #region Function output
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        BytesCopied = $BytesCopied;
        FilesCopied = $CopiedFileCount;
    };
    #endregion Function output
}

$sourcePath = 'D:\Users\Dave'
$destPath = 'Z:\Dave Dimov\Photos\HDD 1'

Copy-WithProgress -Source $srcBase -Destination $dstBase -Verbose | ROBOCOPY $dstBase $dstBase /S /MOVE | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\DaveD\Desktop\LOG.log
```