# Copy-Item command of powershell is not working for large files

Tags: robocopy, copy-item

I am using Copy-Item of powershell to copy files from source to destination. Below is the command which I am using.

```
Copy-Item -Path $fpath -Destination D:\abc\copy_location

$fpath being $fpath = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
```

While testing I found that it was able to copy small files but it wasn't able to copy large files (~300 - 400 MB). I have files max of around 400 MB which I have to copy from source to destination. I saw a post in stackoverflow - "*Copy-Item fails on large file*" where it said to use doubt quotes in the path ... i tried that as well but no success.

Please kindly advise what to do? The other option which I understand is to use robocopy command. The command being:

```
robocopy source destination file_to_copy
```

Here I am facing one issue my source is $fpath, but it gives me the full path upto the file. I only want the path upto the folder.

Comment: What error message do you get? Maybe you wnat to write your own cmdlet? If yes, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434133/progress-during-large-file-copy-copy-item-write-progress

Comment: I don't get any error message... when I go to the destination folder I see that the file is not there ...I don't want to monitor its progress I just want to ensure that the file is fully written before the copy starts.

Comment: please kindly share your views ... I am unable to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Still hit the same problem a few years later, when copying large files from Linux to Windows using PowerShell.  Smaller filers from the same folder were copied successfully, but failed on larger files.  Found a solution at the end of this https://github.com/powershell/powershell/issues/4952

Basically, you need to set MaxEnvelopeSizekb to a bigger value, 1000 worked for me for files over 6MB.