# Copy-Item Progress Bar

Tags: powershell, copy, progress

I have managed to write my first powershell script which helps me to keep my backup organiser and up to date. It is very simple and suites my purpose. Neverthanless I am missing Progress Bar.
My backup folder is almost 10Gb and it is very hard to tell what is the status of copying.

Could You please modify my script to have a progress bar? I am not experienced enought to do it.

```
    $basedir = "Z:\Sales\Meyer Turku\NB-1400_1401 - ICON\MTO100 - NB-1400 - KT30 & KT31\04_Engineering\BG_Ceiling Matrix Backup\00. OLD backup"
$today   = (Get-Date).ToString('dd.MM.yyyy')
$location = New-Item -Path $basedir -Type Directory -Name $today

$sourcePath = "Z:\Sales\Meyer Turku\NB-1400_1401 - ICON\MTO100 - NB-1400 - KT30 & KT31\04_Engineering\BG_Ceiling Matrix\*"
$destPath = "Z:\Sales\Meyer Turku\NB-1400_1401 - ICON\MTO100 - NB-1400 - KT30 & KT31\04_Engineering\BG_Ceiling Matrix Backup\00. OLD backup\$today"
Move-Item -Path $sourcePath -Destination $destPath -Force

$sourcePath = "C:\Users\bartosz.gornicki\Desktop\Travel Pack"
$destPath = "Z:\Sales\Meyer Turku\NB-1400_1401 - ICON\MTO100 - NB-1400 - KT30 & KT31\04_Engineering\BG_Ceiling Matrix"
Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath\* -Destination $destPath -Recurse -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Progress during large file copy (Copy-Item & Write-Progress?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434133/progress-during-large-file-copy-copy-item-write-progress) try to replace

```
Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath\* -Destination $destPath -Recurse -Force
```

With

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $sourcePath\* -Destination $destPath -Description "Backup" -DisplayName "Backup"
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working.

Answer (score 0):

I got something working natively in powershell.
Check out my answer here:
[Progress during large file copy (Copy-Item & Write-Progress?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434133/progress-during-large-file-copy-copy-item-write-progress/76049235#76049235)

It's just a POC, there is not much error handling on it, but it works.

Hope it helps.
Happy scripting!