# Display progress when copying files and folders in powershell

Tags: powershell, copy-item

Sometimes I copy large numbers of files and folders, 2 or more GB.  It would be helpful if I could see how far through the task the program has progressed.

I have been using **Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath -destination $kpath -recurse -force**

This works quite well where $sourcepath is something like "F:\Music\W\Whitlams" (source) and $kpath is something like "K:\W\Whitlams" (destination)

I have tried using write-progress without success.  It appears not to work with the Copy-Item cmdlet.  I had a bit of success with Start-BitsTransfer in that I can get a listing of the files and a progress bar comes up but it does not actually progress.  I would like to get a working progress bar without listing the files/folders being copied.  There are too many to be useful.

I expect that I can monitor progress without significant loss of transfer speed between stations in my windows 10/11 workgroup and without cluttering up the console.

Comment: Check out my answer at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434133/progress-during-large-file-copy-copy-item-write-progress/76049235#76049235
There are a lot of different solutions there also.